# Webkit CSS3 background animation working in Chrome but not Safari

Tags: css, animation, background, css-animations

I have this code

http://jsfiddle.net/4fugqto5/

```
.banner-wrapper {
        animation-name: banner-flash;
        -webkit-animation-name: banner-flash;
        -moz-animation-name: banner-flash;
        animation-duration: 4s;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
        -moz-animation-duration: 4s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }

    @keyframes banner-flash {
        0% { background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/pink.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
        33% { background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/pink.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
        34% { background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/blue.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
        66% { background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/blue.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
        67% { background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/yellow.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
        99% { background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/yellow.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
        100% {background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/pink.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes banner-flash {
        0% { background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/pink.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
        33% { background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/pink.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
        34% { background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/blue.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
        66% { background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/blue.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
        67% { background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/yellow.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
        99% { background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/yellow.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
        100% {background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/pink.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
    }

     @-moz-keyframes banner-flash {
        0% { background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/pink.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
        33% { background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/pink.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
        34% { background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/blue.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
        66% { background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/blue.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
        67% { background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/yellow.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
        99% { background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/yellow.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
        100% {background: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/21/14518/pink.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center; }
    }

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {

        .banner-wrapper {
            background-repeat: no-repeat; 
            background-size: 100%; 
            background-position: center;
        }

        .banner-wrapper img {
            visibility: hidden;
        }

    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="banner-wrapper">
    <img src="pink.png" width="600" height="230" border="0" alt="Miami Nights" style="display: block;" class="image-scale" >
</div>
```

It's a newsletter that has a banner swap targeted to webkit browsers and Apple Mail.

The banner which serves up a a HTML image first then, when viewed in a webkit browser, hides the image then shows the @keyframes animation for the CSS background swap.

My issue is, in Safari, the img is hidden like it should be but then no background is served up

Thanks in advance